# How do I get an rss feed of my reddit saves?

Tags: rss, reddit

Ultimately I'm trying to use IFTTT to transfer pictures I've saved on reddit to google drive, so I can use them as my random desktop pictures. I found this IFTTT recipe: https://ifttt.com/recipes/55843, but I am not sure how to get the rss feed of my reddit saves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit [this page](https://ssl.reddit.com/prefs/feeds/) and you will see a link to your private rss feeds for "your saved links". Use that.